# Realizando comparação tabela temporária

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia,
Tenho dúvida em como realizar uma comparação entre uma tabela temporária com uma tabela do banco de dados.
O que eu quero que retorne é, dentre todos os dados da tabela temporária ele retorne as que tenho no banco(null) e as que não tenho no banco.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
CODIGO VARCHAR(100)
)
...
...
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('20023275000158')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('20023275000158')

UPDATE #TEMP SET CODIGO = '00' + CODIGO WHERE LEN(CODIGO) = 13 -- adiciona 00 antes do número
UPDATE #TEMP SET CODIGO = '0' + CODIGO WHERE LEN(CODIGO) = 14

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

SELECT  DISTINCT    [cbs].[BodyShopId] [Oficina],
        [cbs].[BodyShopBusinessId] [CNPJ],
        [cbs].[AdditionalData].value('(/AdditionalDataForBodyShop/IsDiamond[1]', 'BIT' ) [OficinaDiamante],
        [t].[CODIGO]

FROM        #TEMP t
    LEFT JOIN [Country].[BodyShop] [cbs]
            ON [t].CODIGO = [cbs].[BodyShopBusinessId]

--WHERE [cbs].[AdditionalData].value('(/AdditionalDataForBodyShop/IsDiamond)[1]', 'BIT' ) = 1

order by [Oficina]
```

Comment: Como está declarada a coluna `BodyShopBusinessId`?   Existem linhas com valores repetidos de CPNJ, tanto na tabela `#TEMP` quanto na tabela `BodyShop`?

Comment: Então, pode ser que sim,
Um cliente enviou dados novos, então é possível que contenha casos antigos e novos, entendeu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *O que eu quero que retorne é, dentre todos os dados da tabela temporária ele retorne as que tenho no banco e as que não tenho no banco*

Rudolph, eis uma sugestão.

```
-- código #1 v2
with 
Unico_Temp as (
SELECT CODIGO
  from #TEMP
  where CODIGO is not null
),
Unico_BodyShop as (
SELECT distinct BodyShopBusinessId
  from Country.BodyShop
  where BodyShopBusinessId is not null
)
SELECT T1.CODIGO, 
       case when T2.BodyShopBusinessId is null
                 then 'Não está no banco' 
            else 'Está no banco' end as Observação
  from Unico_Temp as T1
       left join Unico_BodyShop as T2 on T1.CODIGO = T2.BodyShopBusinessId;
```

Comment: Obrigado josé diz pela resposta, porém, o retorno não foi como esperado, pois eu gostaria que retornasse todos os 4000 casos dizendo se tem ou não, e com a querry acima, ele retornou apenas 170.

Comment: @RudolphMühlbauer "4000 casos" é o número de linhas da tabela #TEMP? O código #1 ignorava casos repetidos na tabela #TEMP; alterei-o para tratar todos. Vide código #1 v2.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, o código agora retorna exatamente o que eu queria.